# How to write HTMX with Tailwind Css and Shadcn UI?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, htmx, shadcnui

I found out HTMX seems to be able to replace JavaScript in the client side.

Currently I have a NextJs(ReactJs) project, and how can I convert such a project into HTMX based project while keeping Tailwind and ShadCn UI ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to ShadCn UI Docs at https://ui.shadcn.com/docs, quote: "You can use any framework that supports React. Next.js, Astro, Remix, Gatsby etc.", so ShadCn UI cannot be used with Leptos yet...

But you still can use Tailwind with Leptos:

If you use JS/TS: use HTMX + Astro fullstack + Tailwind

OR
HTMX + Bun + Elysia + Turso(databases)

If you use Rust:  use...
HTMX + Leptos fullstack + Tailwind

Quote from https://leptos.dev/: "Tools like Tailwind integrate with Leptos perfectly..."

or HTMX + Axum backend + Askama HTML templating

Comment: The response mentioned several RUST-related backend frameworks that are unnecessary; that leads reader misunderstanding and wastes time on to find out what  they are.